# How can I build and install PL/R as a non-privileged user?

Tags: compiling, software-installation, non-root-user, postgresql

There is a postgres instance, and I have the ability to build my own instance.

Using [these instructions](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/doc/plr-install.html) I ran:

```
USE_PGXS=1 make
```

which worked but then

```
USE_PGXS=1 make install
```

did not, with this error:

> /bin/sh /usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/mkinstalldirs '/usr/lib64/pgsql'
>   mkdir -p -- /usr/share/pgsql/contrib
>   mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/share/pgsql/contrib': Permission denied
>   make: *** [installdirs] Error 1

Ideally I'd want to install this locally, but I do not know if that is possible.

I am on RedHat 5.

Comment: Hey @A Question Asker: have you been back to try this with the either Chance's answer or the argument order he helped me fix [in my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15182/i-am-not-the-admin-and-want-to-build-and-install-pl-r-locally/15183#15183). It would be nice to know results to the problem so we know if we fixed it or need to keep thinking!

Comment: Caleb, I will update the comments. Thanks for the reminder, I always assume that if an answer isn't found in a couple of hours, nobody will read the q anymore

Comment: That's definitely not the case. There are many mechanisms for finding un-answered questions, even specific to a given interest. Also the SE sites periodically promote old un-answered questions to the home page or shows them to people who statistically might be interested. I've seen years-old questions get answers.

Answer (score 1):

The pl/R list would probably be a better place to ask if you get stuck. Joe Conway also answers questions there. From a quick compile of the pl/R Debian package, it seems like you want to pass a DESTDIR argument to make. Something like

```
make DESTDIR=/home/...
```

Here is the make line from the Debian package

```
USE_PGXS=1 PG_CONFIG=/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_config /usr/bin/make  -C . \   
CFLAGS="-g -Wall -O2" CXXFLAGS="-g -Wall -O2" CPPFLAGS="" LDFLAGS="" \
-I/usr/share/R/include PG_CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/share/R/include
```

and here is the make install line

```
USE_PGXS=1 PG_CONFIG=/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_config /usr/bin/make  -C . \
CFLAGS="-g -Wall -O2" CXXFLAGS="-g -Wall -O2" CPPFLAGS="" LDFLAGS=""  USE_PGXS=1 \   
R_HOME=/usr/lib/R install DESTDIR=debian/tmp/
```

As you can see, there are a lot of other parameters you may want to set. Personally, I'd try to sweet talk your sys admin into installing a binary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to run make with some extra options to specify the location where the software will be installed, probably somewhere in your home folder. You might also have to exclude parts of the install that do things like marking daemons to be run on system startup since your user won't be able to do that.

```
make prefix=/home/username/my_postgres install
```

See the [documentation for make](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Directory-Variables.html) for some more common values that you can set.

Comment: I tried with the prefix and nothing changed. Not sure what you mean about excluding parts of the install.

Comment: Did you make sure the directory you specified as the prefix existed? What was the error this time? Did you try specifying the prefix on the `make` instead of the `make install`?

Comment: Exact same error. I think it just doesn't use the flag.

Comment: maybe `--prefix=/home/username/my_postgres`?

Comment: Actually @Chance from the documentation looks like you only use the dash version of that argument with configure, not with make, but the argument order might matter. @A Question Asker: See my edited answer.

Comment: ah, that makes sense.  Argument first, then target.

Comment: I think prefix can only be set in ./configure. On make it is not changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a `configure` command in the untarred directory?

With some software you can run 
`./configure --prefix=/home/yourname/some_directory`

followed by 
`make` and `make install`.

If anything, after you do your `make` you can manually copy executable files into your `/home/username/bin` directory or anywhere in your path.  Library files can be copied into your `/home/username/lib`.  Anything is possible under your home directory or directories of which you have ownership, it's just a matter of putting them in the right place.

Comment: There is no configure, sadly. I'm not sure about what should be copied, otherwise. I guess I'd have to do a local postgres install? Don't even know if that is possible.

Comment: @A Question Asker, perhaps you can edit the makefile to install in different paths.  For instance, if you see a directory like /usr/local/bin, change to /home/username/bin, likewise for /usr/local/lib.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted.  As I stated in the answer ("some software"), this doesn't always work, but with many software packages it does.